# how can I let the user draw a closed curve [2D] in Python and store those points in a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, draw, curve

My ultimate goal is to let the user draw a closed curve and get a matrix with the positions of those points. Obviously those points would be infinite but lets say they consist of a grid of points that are separated by 0.1 units

Finally I will place any point in the 'canvas' and guess if its inside or outside the curve--> this last part I already know how to do it.

Comment: The user's first click on the canvas starts appending (x,y) points into a list.  Every subsequent click adds another (x,y) point to the list, until some user action indicates the curve is complete and can be automatically closed.  For feedback in a GUI, the first click draws a point on the canvas and subsequent points draw a point and a line from the last point.  For extra swank, draw a "rubberband" line from the last point to the current cursor position and also implement an "undo/redo" mechanism.  Actually **how** to do this depends on the GUI platform you are using, if any.

Answer (score 0):

you need a lib to get you the graphics, then you can read it. for that You're looking for turtle or tkinter:

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html